# Use href without sending cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, cookies, browser

I need to redirect my site to another 3rd party site for auth.

I'm using React.js

> In user browser server set's the cookies. Which is sent along with all the rest API.

Now I want to redirect the user to another 3rd party auth and for that, I'm using the **href** but It will send the cookies along with the request which I don't want.

`<a href={server url} className="link">`

above request will redirect to the server with cookies(which I want to prevent).

> Is is possible to restrict cookies from adding while redirecting to a site using href or windows.location.

Comment: This is really unclear and oddly formatted, perhaps you can clean it up a bit, include a bit of code, an explanation of the specific problem and exactly how it arises?

Comment: @pvg can you check now.

Comment: You can't really control the cookies of a non-origin domain.

Comment: @pvg what do you mean by non-origin? Please explain.

Comment: Is the redirect target (server url) on a different domain?

Comment: @Sag1v No it's same.

Comment: So why sending cookies to your own domain is an issue for you ?